# What is the modern meaning of "送官究辦"

Tags: vocabulary

I saw this word from this:

[image: 送官究辦]

What does it mean?

Comment: "Offenders will be turned over to the court to be dealt with."

Comment: @QuestionMarks That doesn't appear accurate or constructive. Please revise your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

送官究办 *sòng guān jiūbàn* - means [to be sent to court to be dealt with](http://dict.cn/%E9%80%81%E5%AE%98%E7%A9%B6%E5%8A%9E)

送 - to send

官 - means an official building, in this case it means the court

究 - investigate

办 - to be dealt with

Maybe others can provide some insight into whether or not this is still in use

Comment: As you're writing your answer in simplified Chinese, it should be noticed: `究` only sounds **jiū** in mainland Mandarin, though it can be either **jiù** (preferred) or **jiū** in Taiwanese Mandarin.

Comment: @Stan - Thanks for that, I've edited my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Yet ... I'm curious about your avatar. Is the stamp designed by yourself? Its order doesn't coincide with the rules of seal cutting. The correct order (left to right, top to bottom) should be `31/42` or `21/34` but not now `41/32`. You can check this link [篆刻章法: 4．四字印，布排方式有六种](http://www.shufazidian.com/shuji/article.php?arid=41&acid=21) for more information.

Comment: @Stan - I shall plead ignorance. I used an online generator. From memory I wanted something Chinese looking when this site kicked off. I guess I should change it, no point in looking ignorant in the face of facts.

Answer (score 1):

Offenders will be prosecuted by law/the authority.

Answer (score 0):

It just means "if someone breaks the rule, he will get punished."
Actually, this word is seldom used in China Mainland today. It is more common before 1911.

Comment: It's very common in Hong Kong, though seldom used in mainland China.

Comment: It is also quite common in Taiwan.

Comment: @MichaelLai So are Americans making this sign to alert Hong Kong people and Taiwanese? That would be kind of racial prejudice...

Comment: It is rather interesting to see that it is written in traditional Chinese. It might indicate that the sign is either old, or that the communities around the area are mainly from the southern parts of China...